# django unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, exception

i am implementing a django web site,

the site goes to the hello world view:

> http://ec2-107-20-20-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

views.py `/home/ubuntu/djangoProj/micopiloto/portfolio`

```
    # Create your views here.
    from django.http import HttpResponse 

    def view(request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello Worlsss9d!')
```

but i cannot see the amin site, I see this error: `unable to open database file`

```
> http://ec2-107-20-20-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin/

settings.py `/home/ubuntu/djangoProj/micopiloto`


# Django settings for micopiloto project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'thadb.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '2&g_&k=+^(0t)1xf82m^=#0u6v1e!)nn7ixq*+2^h%4$mwlrsm'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'micopiloto.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'portfolio' 
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

so i see the created thadb.db 
in my project folder,

i have the error:

```
Exception Value:    
unable to open database file
```

so I have `$sudo chmod 777 thadb.db`

but still get the same error,

is this because of the permission?
should i set the folder to 777?

EDIT>>

As per suggested solution, i tried chmod root for the db and the root folder

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     ubuntu   44032 2012-04-09 09:49 thadb.db
drwxrwxrwx 3 root   ubuntu 4096 2012-04-09 12:44 micopiloto
```

Still not working! ;(

i get this error:

```
Exception Value:    
unable to open database file
```

So how to make the admin show??

- how will the security be affected?

thanks!

Comment: If you are the owner of the file and you want to restrict access to that file I think that `chmod 700` would be what you need. I you have knowledge and experience with `chmod` then you undoubtedly understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, after much grappling got it to worked, so if another noob haves this problem this is part of the solution[ with making the db file n folder for the db with the right permissions]

the problem was the path for my db on the settings.py

i gave the whole path and then it worked ;)

```
/home/ubuntu/djangoProj/micopiloto/
```

thanks!

Comment: That does work but writing a full path is not a recommended thing, as references should be relative, preferably. But I bet you know all of this.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an article that describes a solution to your problem:

http://www.pantz.org/software/sqlite/unabletoopendbsqliteerror.html

The solution is to make sure the directory containing the database file also has write access allowed to the process.

Also, Django has a page for this problem.

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3

Comment: hi, thanks, i tried this solution but still not working, i have chown  for root the db and the root folder for the app, but still not showing the admin, what else could it be?, thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10071711/11124205

works for me. Try to let www-data write in database directory to let sqlite create the journal file.